# bash: is possible to prefix a command with a directory?

Tags: bash, path

I have a somewhat vexing problem: in a crontab, I'd like to prefix certain programs with a directory. I cannot add all these directories to the `PATH` because the basenames of my programs are not unique (and the dir is supposed to disambiguate them).  An example of what I'd like is the simplest way to explain:

```
PATH=/data/some/place/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

*/15 * * * * foomatic/featurizer > /dev/null 2>&1
*/15 * * * * barmatic/featurizer > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Of course, this doesn't work, even though directories `foomatic/` and `barmatic/` are both under `/data/some/place/bin`, and both have a valid program called `featurizer`.

The only thing I could think of is:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
B=/data/some/place/bin

*/15 * * * * $B/foomatic/featurizer > /dev/null 2>&1
*/15 * * * * $B/barmatic/featurizer > /dev/null 2>&1
```

But it's kind of ugly.

The alternative would be to prefix each `featurizer` program with e.g. `foomatic_` or `barmatic_`, in which case I could add all the directories to the path, but I am not fond of this either (in reality, I have many such programs).

Is there any trick to have `bash` understand `foomatic/featurizer` as a valid command somewhere on the `PATH`?

Comment: Sounds like you've considered all of your reasonable choices: (a) command is in your PATH (the PATH given in the `crontab`), (b) use a auxiliary shell variable (like your `B`), or (c) put the paths in explicitly. If you have several of them the same, I think option (b) is reasonable. Not that ugly. :)

Comment: What's wrong with specifying the full path?

Comment: thanks all for the quick responses. Using `$B/` in front of the commands makes the crontab a wee bit busier visually than I'd like, but that is indeed what I'll end up using.  Using the full path for each command is even worse: lots of repeat, all to be changed if the topdir changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the auxiliary shell variable is not that ugly, and would be fine to use.  Another option is to write a simple wrapper that will search the PATH for you.  For example, call this script `path`:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=:
for i in $PATH; do
    cmd="$i/${1?No command specified}"
    if test -x $cmd; then
        shift
        IFS=$' \t\n'
        exec "$cmd" "$@"
    fi
done
echo Command not found: "$1" >&2
exit 1
```

and invoke it from the crontab as:

```
path foomatic/featurizer
```

Comment: I like it.  I suppose if I were to switch to `zsh`, then I could even work that somehow in the logic of locating commands and hashing them so that subsequent uses don't have to search.  But that would be pointless in the crontab application.  I guess the initial question was due to some mild surprise that neither `bash` nor `zsh`, to my knowledge, understand a command such as `foo/command`. Pity, it would be simple. It's not like I'm asking for some weird wildcard resolution.